# Fliendly_ID - URL not being displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-url, will-paginate, friendly-id, pretty-urls

I am new to ROR and working on a small project. Recently I added the friendly ID gems and followed the instruction on the documentation. But I can't seem to get the URL working. I added the friendly id to communities model which is basically your posts model.

Route code:

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]




  validates :title, :length => { :minimum => 5 }

has_attached_file :post_image, :styles => 
           { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>", :large => "1280x720", :headline => "1280x720"}

validates_attachment_content_type :post_image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

belongs_to :member 
has_many :comments
scope :newest_first, lambda { order("communities.created_at DESC")}
scope :without_community, lambda{|community| community ? {:conditions => ["community.id != ?", @community.id]} : {} }

# def to_param

#   "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"

# end

end
```

I even tried the to_param to get the URL's. But nothing seems to work.

Controller code:

```
class CommunitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_community, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  layout "community"
  before_filter :authenticate_member!, except: [:index, :show]
  require 'will_paginate/array'

  # GET /communities
  # GET /communities.json
  def index
    @communities = Community.newest_first.friendly.where(params[:id]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
  end

  # GET /communities/1
  # GET /communities/1.json
  def show
    @communities = Community.newest_first.friendly.where(params[:title]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).where('id NOT IN (?)', @community.id)

  end

  # GET /communities/new
  def new
    @community = Community.new({:member_id => current_member.id})
  end

  # GET /communities/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /communities
  # POST /communities.json
  def create
    @community = Community.new(community_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @community.save
        format.html { redirect_to @community, notice: 'Post: #{@community.title.capitalize} was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @community }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /communities/1
  # PATCH/PUT /communities/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @community.update(community_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @community, notice: 'Post: #{@community.title.capitalize} was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @community }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /communities/1
  # DELETE /communities/1.json
  def destroy
    @community.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to communities_url, notice: 'Post: #{@community.title.capitalize} was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_community
      @community = Community.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def community_params
      params.require(:community).permit(:name,:post_image, :title, :content, :member_id)
    end
end
```

But If I type the URL like http://localhost:3000/communities/post.title I am able to go directly to the post. That means the slugs have been created and they are working kind of. But I can't seem to get them displayed on the URL.
I have tried many permutation and combinations but nothing seems to work.

Would really appreciate any help. Let me know if there is any other specific code you require.

FYI: Migrations code:

```
class AddSlugToCommunities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :communities, :slug, :string, limit: 191
    add_index :communities, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

Friendly_ID migration code:

```
class CreateFriendlyIdSlugs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :friendly_id_slugs do |t|
      t.string   :slug,           :null => false, limit: 191
      t.integer  :sluggable_id,   :null => false
      t.string   :sluggable_type, :limit => 50
      t.string   :scope, limit: 191
      t.datetime :created_at
    end
    add_index :friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_id
    add_index :friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type]
    add_index :friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type, :scope], :unique => true
    add_index :friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_type
  end
end
```

Comment: did you add slug in community model?

Comment: Yes, I have. See the edit for the migration code. I can view the slugs in the database. I can even visit the post/community using the slug instead of the ID in the URL. But I am unable to get the slug in the URL after going through a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went deeper into the code and found that slugs were being made. its just that the URL was not being linked properly. Made a few changes to the links to to use slugs instead of :id to get it working.

Thanks anyways @uzaif